# How Can Fixed This Erorr (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null. )

Tags: c#, datagridview

How Can Fixed This Error When return null

This is the relevant code part:

```
        private void DgvIncome_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            //try
            {
                txtCode.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtRecNo.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtMembershipID.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                txtGustName.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                txtGustMobile.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                txtNote.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                txtSalesNo.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                txtMainPackageNo.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                txtSubPackageNo.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                txtPackageNo.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                txtNatPrice.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                txtDiscount.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                dtpStartDate.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
                dtpEndDate.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                ShowSalesName();
                ShowMainPackageName();
                ShowSubPackageName();
                ShowPackageName();
                ShowPrice();
                chbxSearch.Checked = false;
            }
```

**Error:** When select a row, there are empty values ,

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You will almost always get the same results but faster if you google the actual exception - in this case. NullReferenceException

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on what you want to happen in case the cell value is null. The easiest way to deal with it would be using the ? operator like this:

```
txtCode.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value?.ToString();
```

This would assign null to to the Text property of the textboxes in case the cell value is null which is probably what you'd want.

see https://csharp.today/c-6-features-null-conditional-and-and-null-coalescing-operators/

Answer (score 0):

txtCode.Text = dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value != null ? dgvIncome.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() : "";

This will assign null value in case of getting null values always

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34475578)